# edit count difference

Tags: discussion, editing, badges

There is a difference in approved edits and actual edits in my profile

*Editor Stats* shows

> Mudit Kapil had 503 edit suggestions approved, and 67 edit suggestions rejected

But *Badge progress* shows 452 edit suggestions approved so there is a total difference of 51 approved edits in both the stats.

Does it mean that 51 edited posts has been deleted from the site?

Why there is a difference in counts in  Editor  Stats and Badge progress?

Comment: The badge description says "excludes deleted and tag edits". That probably makes up the difference right there.

Comment: @Seth `ReplyAsAnswer.set(True)`

Comment: @ThomasW. done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description for the badge says this:

> (excluding.. deleted posts and tag edits).

That is probably making the difference for you.

Comment: Perhaps caching also has an effect, since counts for badges are updated with cron jobs